# Second monitor does not work

Tags: video, monitor

Ubuntu 22.04.3 does not recognize my second monitor connected with DVI cable.
It identifies on "monitors" but does not play video

Comment: It identifies on System Profiler -> Computer -> Displays -> Monitors, but doesn't show on Settings -> Displays ?